# Is there a way to make secondary interface as eth0 in azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

In Azure when creating interface through ARM template,one of the interface has to be assigned as primary and that interface becomes as eth0.Is there a way through which eth0 can become a secondary interface and not primary

Comment: What is the reason you do not give a response to get more help and also do not accept the answer? Just read the rules of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to change the primary network interface into the secondary. A VM must have at least one network interface attached to it. You cannot change the primary into the secondary and the secondary into the primary at the same time. I don't know what is the special reason you need to do this, but the end answer is no.

Comment: The reason for doing is that application gateway sends traffic to the first interface of vmss but the vmss created by us has two interface and we want the traffic to be processed by the secondary interface.We also tried changing the net plan but the changed value is not getting reflected.

Comment: @Rahul It's really impossible. You only can recreate a suitable vmss with one NIC.

Comment: @Rahul Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.